# C - strtod() does not recognise the decimal dot

Tags: c, strtod

I have a buffer in which there are "random" numbers, separated by a coma. For example :

"1589.3,12478.359,485.39971" etc

I need to check the length of the decimal part and the integer part.

I made some research, and I decided to use the strtod() on my buffer, in order to get one number.

However, it doesn't work as intended. So I tried on a simple example :

```
int number;
char myNumber[10] = "3113.14";
number = strtod (myNumber,NULL);
printf("%d\n", number);
```

This prints 3113, so I made some research and I found that I should use %f because it's not an integer.

So I corrected it :

```
int number;
char myNumber[10] = "3113.14";
number = strtod (myNumber,NULL);
printf("%f\n", number);
```

And then it prints me 0.000000

I tried with a coma (,), with the dot from the regular jeyboard (.) and the dot from the numeric pad (.). They all give me the same result.

I am using dev c++ (I can't choose, I am not admin on my working station).

Thanks for your attention and your help :)

Comment: Check your LOCALE settings

Comment: Does the program call `setlocale()`? The decimal point symbol is taken from the active locale (defaults to "C" if not explicitly configured)

Answer (score 4):

Use a type double:

```
double number;
char myNumber[10] = "3113.14";
number = strtod (myNumber,NULL);
printf("%lf\n", number);
```

Comment: Thank you very much to take time to answer to someone as stupid as me.